# postgres how to get column size for char varchar and text data types

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm trying get column size from query using postgres C api functions.

```
CREATE TABLE char_length_test (c char(3), vc varchar(5), t text)
```

For example I have this query:

```
SELECT c, vc, repeat(c, 1), t from char_length_test
```

I get correct types, but I cant figure it out how to get column size. I've tried using `PQfsize` and `PQgetlength`.

- `PQfsize` returns `-1`, which means variable size according to postgres documentation while I need column size.
- `PQgetlength` returns `0`, which is fine, since table does not contain any data, though its not column size.

I'm expecting to get length `3` for `c`, `5` for 'vc' and a big value for `repeat(c, 1)` function and `t`

To be honest I was expecting functionality similar to `mysql_fetch_fields`.

Comment: Maybe PQfmod for varchar(n)? Don't know.

Comment: btw, If you'll post the answer I'll mark it -_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [PQfmod](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQFMOD).

> The interpretation of modifier values is type-specific; they typically indicate precision or size limits. The value -1 is used to indicate "no information available". Most data types do not use modifiers, in which case the value is always -1.